# Messed Up My Computer, Badly

Tags: macos

I was testing a file IO thing, and accidentally hit an infinite loop. I was able to stop it relatively quickly (only about 23k files were created). It happened on my Desktop, and when I try to view my computer, it just freezes up and I can't do anything after about 30 seconds. I wrote a script to fix it:

```
Dir.glob "*".grep /\d/.each do |f|
  system("rm #{f}")
end
```

but that freezes as well. Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: What's the OS? Try running fsck on Unix/Linux or chkdsk on windows first

Comment: @Dougvj The question is tagged OSX.

Comment: I don't know much about OSX, but is it possible to log in to a text mode shell rather than the graphics environment?

Comment: @MrLister: yep, it's call Single User mode, invoked by holding down `CMD`+`S` when you hear the gong while booting.  It gives you a root shell but you need to follow the on screen instructions to get the file system mounted write-enabled.

Comment: OK, and do you have any file alteration monitors running then, like `famd`? Because I'm guessing that is part of the problem.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to try inserting your Mac OSX install CD. If you boot from it, you should be able to open up a terminal window. From there you can use the command

```
rm -f /Users/[YourUserName]/desktop/*
```

That will remove everything on your Desktop without asking "Are you Sure?". Make *sure* you select the right path, else you may delete very important files.

If you have files on your desktop that you need to keep, use the command

```
mv /Users/[YourUserName]/desktop/[Filename] /Destination/Path/Here
```

That will move those files you want to keep to the path specified at the end of the command.

Again, be very careful using the rm -f command. It will remove files without asking if you're sure, including important system files. That's why it's important you double and triple check you have the appropriate directory.

Answer (score 0):

When booting up your Mac, hold command+s this will take you into single user mode. Type the following to mount the file system:

```
mount -uw /
```

After that:

```
rm -f /Users/[username]/Desktop/*
```

You won't have to have the Mac OS X install DVD this way